# How to show parent objects attribute in gridview? ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, one-to-many

Lets say i've got an employee table, and a company table. Every employee belongs to a company, so there is a foreign key column in the employee table on the company table.

I've created a gridview component on the default.aspx, for the employee and bound it to the database table with an sqldatasource. So I can see all the data, but i would like that instead of the company_id field, the gridview would show the companys name, which the user belongs to.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should deal with it in data layer, not UI. Use SQL Join in SelectCommand property of SqlDataSource.

More about SQL Join types:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html